# Onmouseover / out Code Don't Work in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, dictionary, onmouseover

I am working on a map that shows our branchs. When mouse on one of our branchs, it shows a different picture over the city. 
For that, i prepered a html page with the codes below and its work! But when i copy the codes to my wordpress page it is not working!

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<body>

<center><img src="TurkeySvg.png" usemap="#harita" ></center>
<map name="harita">
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('tshirt').style.display='block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('tshirt').style.display='none';">
<area shape="rect" coords="1081,244,1227,347" href="" onmouseover="this.src='samsun.png';"></a>
</map>
<div id="tshirt" style="position: absolute; left: 55%; top: 15px; width: whatever, height: whatever; border: 2px solid #000000; display: none;">
<img src="samsun.png" />
</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

I copy/paste the code to my wordpress page in html area and correct the picture links, but it just shows the background picture.

You can see my wordpress page here: https://www.firfir.org/tr/harita/

Comment: you need widths and heights especially on the `a` tag...just to get it working. `map>a{display: block;height: 20px; width: 20px;}` this wil atleast get the hover state working

Answer (score 0):

One problem i see straight away is that your `<head>` tag closes at the wrong place:

> Close it before the opening `<body>` tag.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
 </head>

    <body>

    </body>
 </html>
```

just an example to help you get it working:

`display: block;` is important for the a tag, but my point is that it is working on that page of yours you cant get a result if the `a` tag with the hover state has no width & height because then the HTML page renders no element and without the element their is no hover state.

> Changed the image width just to make it fit so you can see a result

```css
map>a,map>a>p {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

img {
width: 50%;
}

#tshirt {
    position: absolute;
    width: 11%;
    height: 7%;
    left: 48%;
    top: 46px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p></p>
    <center><img src="https://www.firfir.org/tr/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/TurkeySvg.png" usemap="#harita"></center>
    <p></p>
    <map name="harita" style="min-height: 1px;height: 20px;width: 20px;">
    <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('tshirt').style.display='block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('tshirt').style.display='none';" style="display: block;height: 20px;width: 20px;">
    <p>Hover me to see result</p>
    <area shape="rect" coords="1081,244,1227,347" href="" onmouseover="this.src='samsun.png';"></a><br>
    </map>
<div id="tshirt"><img src="https://www.firfir.org/tr/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/samsun.png"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use the <p> line because of that i want use 7 seperate city for this. Could it work again like this?

Comment: im sorry @OğuzhanEker but now im verry confused with what you are asking? where do you want the hover effect? at the bottom of the map? and do you want a city name then hovering that name display the city with overlay image on map?

Comment: Okey. I write the city name, with css get the name to over map. I tried with your codes with a html page and its ok. It is working. But when i get the codes to wordpress page, the css is not working.(I tried to write css code to page html side and also style.css)

Comment: i actually think i see the problem, ill update my answer quickly

Comment: @OğuzhanEker do not add your style tag as a HTML element ,try adding your styles to the end of this doc `/themes/consulting/assets/css/layout_1/main.css?ver=4.0.2`

Comment: also if you copy it into worpress page , dont add the `<html><head><style></style><body>` just add from `<center` to the last closing `<div>` , wordpress should automatically add the head an body tags. Also you cant copy a <style> tag within the CMS wordpress page it will break, add as mentioned in previous comment

Comment: Hi again @ylama! I did what you say. Write the html code to page, and css code to style.css. I write the city name and take the name to over the map. But my css code about the font is not working. (I want to city name style white color, bold etc. but although i write the css, it is not working). The page is here: https://www.firfir.org/tr/harita/